# UEFI/legacy issue : Ubuntu alongside Win10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I'm pretty much new on Linux and was planing to make dual-boot for a long time now.

My problem basically is that after I installed ubuntu (16.04) alongside my windows 10 it can boot if i set legacy first, but there is no GRUB or any other bootloader, so, when i set `legacy` first ubuntu loads, but when i set `uefi` first windows 10 loads, also without any bootloader,

Problem is I don't want to shift options `legacy/efi` all the time depending on what OS I need to use. And I need them both because of my job. There are no apps and programs I have to use daily for linux.

So please, someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dealt with my problem by formating partitions and installing Ubuntu from Efi USB option in BIOS. Thanks everyone :D

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, also windows 10 will boot right if you use legacy:

Legacy first, Legacy OPROM and everything on legacy.
Install Ubuntu, when it finishes you can boot from a menu that appears everytime you boot either win 10 or ubuntu.

Comment: Can you please explain it more deeply please.
What is Legacy OPROM and I when I put legacy first, when i had only windows without ubuntu it wouldn't load only  "_" was on screen :/

Comment: In BIOS options(OPROM is a option) legacy everything is what I did, your win10 will load normally if you go with legacy. when you dual-boot you see your windows partition as /sda/ windows 10 just scrolll down and thats it

Comment: Problem is I don't have bootloader that gives me opportunity to chose for OS i wish to boot.  And I don't really have OPROM option in BIOS , and i did legacy everything I could :/

P.S. Is OPROM short for something?

Comment: Bootloader only appears once you installed ubuntu, windows 10 be default loads normally, when you install ubuntu then you get a screen for OS to boot. OPROM is a setting not sure what it means but helps to have it in legacy mode.

Comment: Yeah, but now when I have ubuntu and windows there is no bootloader...

Comment: no bootloader? did you install ubuntu alongside windows 10? there was an option in the installer to dual boot

Comment: So, maybe I was a bit unclear.
I have win 10, and I installed ubuntu alongside it on separate partitions, 2 (each 100 GB) one is / and other /home, when i installed i used option other so I can format free partitions.

Comment: make sure you dont delete small partitions, because thats the bootloader

Comment: Yes.... it is suposed to show but it does not... that is my problem. Everything in BIOS is on legacy and everything related to fast boot for windows is turned off and I didn't delete small partitions. When i was installing Ubuntu i shrinked E:\ partition of windows and the split it on 2 parts, each 100 GB

Comment: Do you have the windows 10 iso, maybe you need to re-install windows or ubuntu, I did the same like you but it does show on the menu